# Print Method in NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numberator, denominator);   
}


Fraction *myFraction = [Fraction new];

        [myFraction setNumberator:1];
        [myFraction setDenominator:3];
```

Now I have other methods made like dividing both numerator  and denominator etc. But i want to add in my [myFraction] in the NSLog with everything else rather than on a new line

```
NSLog(@"The value of my fraction is: %i/%i which equals to: %.3g * 100 = %.4g%%", [myFraction numberator], [myFraction denominator], [myFraction convertToNum], [myFraction multiplyBy100]);
```

is there anyway i can add in the [myFractions print] where the two %i %i is, so i don't have to type in [myFraction numerator/denominator]

eg.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myFractions Print];
```

result: 1/3

Comment: *numerator*, not *numberator*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use`description` method. You can override it in your class to return string representation of your class.

In your case you can use the following code:

```
-(NSString*) description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator];   
}
```

to print the object you can then use it like this

```
NSLog("Fraction = %@", yourFractionObj);
```

See [Describing objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-SW5).

Comment: This works, but don't rely on `description` in production code to produce strings for display in the UI.  It is really only intended for debugging and logging.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your print method, override the description method on your Fraction class like this:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/%i", numberator, denominator];   
}
```

The description method is automatically called when you print an object using NSLog, so you can now write logs like this:

```
NSLog(@"The value of my fraction is: %@ which equals to: %.3g * 100 = %.4g%%", myFraction, [myFraction convertToNum], [myFraction multiplyBy100]);
```

If you need the print method for another reason you can now write it like this:

```
- (void) print {
    NSLog(@"%@", self);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **func** or **FUNCTION**. It will print the method name with class name. For Example

NSLog(@"%s",`__func__`);